# How can I share my home folder between an elementary OS laptop and Windows 10 desktop?

Tags: release-freya, microsoft-windows

I have a laptop with elementary OS Freya. I also have a desktop PC with Windows 10. My desktop PC is situated at my workplace, and sometimes I need to continue work after office closing time on my laptop when I get home. I used to just email work back and forth between my office and personal email address to continue work, but this is becoming tedious.

Ideally, I would like to be able to share the entirety of the 'home' directory (pictures, downloads, documents, everything) with this Windows PC. I would like it so that I can update a document on my laptop and can then immediately access it the next day at work, and, when I've finished with it at the end of the working day, the updated version is on my laptop. I have read about something called SSH, but didn't understand. If there is a way to do this, a step-by-step guide for a beginner to Linux would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is a conventional cloud service like Dropbox, Google Drive or OneDrive an option for you? At least for Dropbox the client works great and will allow you to share files easily.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### 1. Using a cloud-based solution

Sync your `/home` partition to some cloud service and use it on both of your computers.

### 2. Remotely control your elementary OS

This works only if your home device is turned on all of the time and if you know the IP address of it (note: it probably changes. Basically, what you're going to need is SSH (if you're good with terminal), VNC client, TeamViewer or whatever. TeamViewer might be the easiest to use because it's a well-known brand that supports Linux perfectly, with VNC clients right behind it. SSH is suitable for those who are comfortable with using the terminal since it offers no graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use Dropbox, Copy, Google Drive or some other cloud service.